# Trying to get latest page status via Facebook PHP SDK with a cron

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to pull the latest status from a Facebook page with the PHP SDK then insert it as a post into my website via a cron job, but seem to be stuck on the access token part. Here's what I have so far:

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php';
require 'wp-load.php';

// I replaced these obviously
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => FB_APP_ID,
  'secret' => FB_SECRET,
));

try {
  $feed = $facebook->api('/322522705880/feed?limit=1');
}  catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  error_log($e);
}
```

Then I use $feed['data'][0]['description'] etc to create the post with. However, the only time I can get $feed to have any data is when I reinstall a Facebook Wordpress plugin that must activate an access token some how because it will then work for a few hours, and then stop. I can't find any info anywhere at all on how I would generate one of my own from a script, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getAccessToken/ doesn't really provide any helpful info. If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great. The wordpress plugin is doing this somehow, I just need to know how to replicate it.

I did some poking around in the plugin and found this

```
$token = false;

if (!$token) {
    // Get temporary token
    $token = $this->model->fb->getAccessToken();
    if (!$token) return false;

    // Exchange it for the actual long-term token
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={$app_id}&client_secret={$app_secret}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token={$token}";
    $page = wp_remote_get($url, array(
        'method'        => 'GET',
        'timeout'       => '5',
        'redirection'   => '5',
        'user-agent'    => 'wdfb',
        'blocking'      => true,
        'compress'      => false,
        'decompress'    => true,
        'sslverify'     => false
    ));
    if(is_wp_error($page)) return false; // Request fail
    if ((int)$page['response']['code'] != 200) return false; // Request fail

    parse_str($page['body'], $response);
    $token = isset($response['access_token']) ? $response['access_token'] : false;
    if (!$token) return false;
}
```

But that gives me "No user access token specified" and I'm not sure how to use or get a user access token for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to have for this is an application token. You can "build" an app access token using your app_id and app_secret:

```
access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET
```

That's a pipe character `|` between the two values.

Once you have this, you can just make a request to an endpoint like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed?limit=1&access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET
```

The response will be something like this:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "40796308305_10152854866613306",
         "from": {
            "name": "Verone Diedericks",
            "id": "100003842548992"
         },
         "to": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "category": "Food/beverages",
                  "name": "Coca-Cola",
                  "id": "40796308305"
               }
            ]
         },
         "message": "Vony nd kimo or just vony",
         "privacy": {
            "value": ""
         },
         "type": "status",
         "created_time": "2013-11-26T20:13:11+0000",
         "updated_time": "2013-11-26T20:13:11+0000"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/40796308305/feed?limit=1&access_token=163586277060593|Rtsz7h6IiHu7Uva9D5S4VW0FKu8&since=1385496791&__previous=1",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/40796308305/feed?limit=1&access_token=163586277060593|Rtsz7h6IiHu7Uva9D5S4VW0FKu8&until=1385496790"
   }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, when I try this on a Facebook page, "data" is empty, same problem that I'm having with the PHP SDK. This is the page I'm getting a status from https://www.facebook.com/KurtzRealEstate so I used https://graph.facebook.com/322522705880/feed?limit=1&access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET. Same thing with https://graph.facebook.com/KurtzRealEstate/feed?limit=1&access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET

Comment: That page is not public so this won't work. You also didn't use your application details.

Comment: Sorry, for security reasons I left that out the same as you, but I guess it doesn't matter https://graph.facebook.com/322522705880/feed?limit=1&access_token=215222141972653|f8ecf1e8eaf1fe02119710cc267b7d77 same thing, and the page is set to Published so it is public unless there's a setting else where that I can't find.

Comment: There must be another setting - I can not reach that page.

Comment: AHHHHHH you're right. This entire time it's just been because someone set the page to only be visible to the U.S., forcing a login in order to see it. Thank you.